# Disabled attribute for anchor tag not working

Tags: javascript, html

I have a requirment where i need to disable onclick event on href tag. I am able to disable "a href" tag,but still onclick event within "a href" tag is not getting disabled.

Below snippet explains the issue more clearly!

```js
//click works on button even though it is disabled 
function check(){
alert("i am able to click on button though it is disabled")
}
```

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<a href="#" id="tr" onclick="check()" class="btn btn-warning" disabled>Click</a>
```

In the above snippet even though "a href" seems to be disabled but when you click on the a-href still click works!

Please help me!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can try unbind() to remove the click event from your link, or you can return false from the check() function.

Comment: You should prevent default behavior of a link by calling event.preventDefault();
event is passed into event handler.

Answer (score 0):

It's because disabled property only work on a button elment so modify your anchor to become a button:

```
<button type="button" id="tr" onclick="check()" class="btn btn-warning" disabled>Click</button>
```